# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

Here is the complete error

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`permission_role` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
`permission_role` add constraint `permission_role_permission_id_foreign` foreign key (`permission_id`) references `permissions` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

Here is my database migration.

setup_authorization_table

```
public function up()
    {
        // Create table for storing roles
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('removable')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Create table for storing permissions
        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('removable')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Create table for associating permissions to roles (Many-to-Many)
        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
        });
    }
```

What is the error and how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Please dont paste a full error message in the title. Articulate something. The error in the title and the error in the question are different, what is the code for the users table?

Comment: Try splitting those to three migrations, one for `roles`, then for `permissions`, then `permission_role`.

Comment: I can create 3 separate migrations however, that wouldn't solve the problem as the issue is with foreign key references. Also, I am facing this same issue in 3 other tables. So, I believe the issue is with foreign key syntax or the way I reference my foreign keys.

Comment: Hint: what is the primary key of `roles` and `permissions`?